# Group Congruence on a Free monogenic semigroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, congruence-relations

> > **Definition 1:** Consider $S = \{ a, a^2, \dots, a^n, \cdots \}$ is a semigroup under the operation
> >     $$ a^i a^j = a^{i+j}  \; \; \forall i,j \in \mathbb N$$
> >     is called a free monogenic semigroup.
> >
> > **Definition 2:** A equivalence relation $\rho$ on a set $S$ is a *congruence* if 
> >     $$(\forall s, t, a\in S) (s, t)\in \rho \implies (sa, ta) , (as, at)\in \rho.$$
> >
> > **Definition 3:** A congruence relation on $S$ is said to be group congruence if $S/ \rho$ is group under the binary operation
> >     $$(a\rho) (b\rho) = ab\rho$$
> >
> > - Define a relation $\rho_n$ on $S$ by
> >       $$ a^r \rho_n a^s \Longleftrightarrow \; r \equiv s (\text{mod n)}  $$

I have prove that $\rho_n$ is a group congruence and $S/ \rho_n$ isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_n$

Question

> > If $\rho$ is a group congruence on $S$, then $\rho = \rho_n$ for some $n \in  \mathbb N$.

My attempt is

Suppose $\rho$ is a group congruence on $S$, then define 
$$n = \text{min} \{ | r-s| : (a^r, a^s) \in \rho \backslash 1_S \} $$
where $1_S$ is the diagonal realtion on $S$. Clearly if $|r-s| < n$, then $(a^r, a^s) \notin \rho$, so $a\rho$, $a^2\rho$, $\cdots, a^{n}\rho$ are all distinct classes.I want to show that $(a, a^n) \in\rho, \; (a^2, a^{n+1} ) \in \rho$ and so on. Also $\exists r \in \mathbb N$ such that $(a^r, a^{n+r}) \in \rho$. I am stuck here.

Please help.

Comment: But clearly $n=0$, since $(a^r,a^r)\in\rho$. How can then $|r-s|<n$ ever materialize?

Comment: @ Alvin : I have missed something, so i have improved $n $ at my attempt. I think this can work.

Comment: "Suppose $\rho$ is a group congruence on $S$ and $a^0 \rho$ is the identity element of $S/\rho$" There is no such thing as $a^0\rho$, since that notation implies that $a^0\in S$, which is not true. You will have to choose a _positive_ exponent. I recommend you pick the smallest possible, because I suspect that that is more convenient.

Comment: Edited it @ Arthur